# Capybara::ElementNotFound using 'find_field'

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am writing a capybara test in rspec where I am trying to find the count of an element with it's attribute having a specific value. My DOM has following element:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="some_id" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2 2" enable-background="previous 0 0 2 2">
<svg version="1.1" id="some_id" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2 2" enable-background="previous 0 0 2 2">
<svg version="1.1" id="some_id" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 5 7" enable-background="Hello 0 0 5 7">
```

I want to find the count of the element having enable-background value as "previous 0 0 2 2" or maybe viewBox value as "0 0 2 2". I tried the following:

```
expect(find_field("enable-background", {with: "previous 0 0 2 2"}).count).to eq(2)
```

Error I am getting: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "enable-background" with value "previous 0 0 2 2"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - `expect(find_all('svg[viewBox="0 0 2 2"]').count).to eq(2)`

Comment: If you want to know the count then find_all/all is correct, if on the other hand you want to verify the count is a specific number as your answer does, you should write it as `expect(page).to have_selector('svg[viewBox="0 0 2 2"]', count: 2)` - which will reduce the potential flakiness of tests by allowing Capybara to use its waiting behavior